# On Kubuntu 19.10, double clicking a window title bar doesn't switch it between maximied and restore states

Tags: kubuntu, window-manager, plasma-5

When I double-click on the title bar of any window, nothing happens. I notice that on the first click I get the Move pointer, and if enabled I get the geometry displays.

Double-click works fine everywhere else, so I don't think it's my mouse(*).

In `Window management>Window behavior>Titlebar actions>Title bar`, `Double-click` is set to `Maximize` (but all other actions seem to be ignored as well).

Known problem? Any working around such as editing some config file somewhere?

My `~/.config/kwinrc`:

```
[MouseBindings]
CommandActiveTitlebar1=Raise
CommandActiveTitlebar2=Start window tab drag
CommandActiveTitlebar3=Operations menu
CommandAll1=Move
CommandAll2=Toggle raise and lower
CommandAll3=Resize
CommandAllKey=Alt
CommandAllWheel=Nothing
CommandInactiveTitlebar1=Activate and raise
CommandInactiveTitlebar2=Start window tab drag
CommandInactiveTitlebar3=Operations menu
CommandTitlebarWheel=Switch to Window Tab to the Left/Right
CommandWindow1=Activate, raise and pass click
CommandWindow2=Activate and pass click
CommandWindow3=Activate and pass click
CommandWindowWheel=Scroll

[Plugins]
kwin4_effect_dialogparentEnabled=false
kwin4_effect_fadeEnabled=false
kwin4_effect_scaleEnabled=true
windowgeometryEnabled=true

[Windows]
ActiveMouseScreen=false
AutoRaise=false
AutoRaiseInterval=750
AutogroupInForeground=true
AutogroupSimilarWindows=false
BorderSnapZone=10
CenterSnapZone=0
ClickRaise=true
DelayFocusInterval=300
FocusPolicy=ClickToFocus
FocusStealingPreventionLevel=1
GeometryTip=true
HideUtilityWindowsForInactive=true
InactiveTabsSkipTaskbar=false
MaximizeButtonLeftClickCommand=Maximize
MaximizeButtonMiddleClickCommand=Maximize (vertical only)
MaximizeButtonRightClickCommand=Maximize (horizontal only)
NextFocusPrefersMouse=false
Placement=Smart
SeparateScreenFocus=false
ShadeHover=false
ShadeHoverInterval=250
SnapOnlyWhenOverlapping=false
TitlebarDoubleClickCommand=Maximize
WindowSnapZone=10
```

(*) By the way, I don't see any mouse settings to change the double-click delay (but it is fine as it is).

Comment: I'm using Plasma 5.18.3 on Kubuntu 19.10. `Double-click` to maximize works for me. I changed that to maximize vertically only to identify which file is written to. It's `~/.config/kwinrc`. In it, there's the `[Windows]` section near the bottom and it has, among other entries, `TitlebarDoubleClickCommand=Maximize (vertical only)`. PS: I too don't know if there's a setting for double-click interval.

Comment: Also, have you installed any kwin scripts or made any window rules that maybe somehow overriding the *double-click on titlebar to maximize* function?

Comment: Not added anything. No rules, and the only script active is the "Enforce window decorations...". Added my `kwinrc` to the question.

Comment: Just a guess but `CommandActiveTitlebar2=Start window tab drag` and `CommandInactiveTitlebar2=Start window tab drag` maybe interfering in some way?

Comment: I reset them and didn't see any changes. Also tried reset to defaults (which did reset to defaults, including aforementioned problem).

Answer (score 0):

it does not exactly answer your questions like you asked. but my favorite way to maximize is to alt-grab the window with the mouse and drag it to the top of the screen. it will be maximized.

dragging it back from the maximize state to the center of the screen will restore its size

and if you did not know already, you can also drag in the corners and side for tiling 2x2 or 1x2

hope this helps